# Querying a related model within a Laravel query scope

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I have a query scope method that filters results on a Foo model by the author of the model. The complication is that the author is not directly related.

Foo belongs to Bar and Bar belongs to User. If Foo belonged to User, I could just do this:

```php
public function scopeAuthorOnly($query, User $user)
{
    return $query->whereuser_id($user->id);
}
```

This obviously won't work as the Foo model has no user_id column and instead has a bar_id column. However I'm not sure how I can build the query in a way that would filter the user_id.

Any pointers?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Found a solution:

```
public function scopeAuthorOnly($query, User $user)
{
    $query
        ->join('bars', 'foos.bar_id', '=', 'bars.id')
        ->join('users', 'bars.user_id', '=', 'users.id')
        ->where('users.id', '=', $user->id);

    return $query;
}
```

Comment: I have posted a Laravel-way answer, please also check that.

Comment: This is better then whereHas because it uses table index and work more efficient, but do not forget to add ->select("users.*") otherwise laravel can give you "id" or any other field from wrong table, and no error will be thrown.

Comment: This is better if you're stuck with MySQL. Other engines may result errors on such queries. OP never mentioned which DB engine he's using.

Answer (score 20):

You can use `whereHas()` in scopes to query relationships.

Let's assume you have a `users()` relation function in this model. Then it'd be something like this:

```
public function scopeAuthorOnly($query, User $user)
{
    return $query->whereHas('users', function($q) use($user){
        $q->where('id', $user->id);
    });
}
```

**Update:** You can also nest `whereHas` statements: If the current `Foo` has a relation named `bar`, and `bar` has a relation called `users`, it'd be like this:

```
public function scopeAuthorOnly($query, User $user)
{
    return $query->whereHas('bar', function($q) use($user){
        return $q->whereHas('users', function($q2) use($user){
            $q2->where('id', $user->id);
        });
    });
}
```

More info: [here](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#querying-relations)

Comment: The question asked for a solution where Foo belongs to Bar and Bar belongs to User. Your answer assumes Foo belongs directly to User.

Answer (score 8):

You can also do this using relations (without resorting to manual joins):

```
public function scopeAuthorOnly($query, User $user)
{
    $query->whereHas(array('Bar' => function($query) use($user){
                $query->where('user_id', '=', $user->id);
            }));
}
```

Edit: now using `whereHas` instead of `with` (Laravel >= 4.1 only). Thanks for the correction Arda.

Edit: in 4.2 the syntax of whereHas has changed, so that the relationship name is parameter 1 and the closure is parameter 2 (rather than being passed in as an array):

```
public function scopeAuthorOnly($query, User $user)
{
    $query->whereHas('Bar', function($query) use($user){
                $query->where('user_id', '=', $user->id);
            });
}
```

Comment: This will not affect main query filtering, but only fill affect the results in relation.

Comment: Thanks for the correction regarding the use of `whereHas` instead of `with` to affect the main query.